# Simple CSS/HTML Menu links not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this navigation menu but links without a  (like the first link) don't work. any ideas what this could be?

```
<div id="nav">
<li><a href="/admin/index.php">Dashboard</a></li>
<li><a>Contacts</a>
    <ul>
    <li><strong>Companies</strong></li>
    <li><a href="/admin/index.php?id=customer/addcustomer">Add Company</a></li>
    <li><a href="/admin/index.php?id=customer/viewcustomer">View Company</a></li>
    <li><strong>Contacts</strong></li>
    <li><a href="/admin/index.php?id=contacts/addcontact">Add Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="/admin/index.php?id=contacts/viewcontact">View Contact</a></li>
    <li><strong>Resellers</strong></li>
    <li><a href="/admin/index.php?id=reseller/addreseller">Add Reseller</a></li>
    <li><a href="/admin/index.php?id=reseller/viewreseller">View Reseller</a></li>
    <li><strong>Salesman</strong></li>
    <li><a href="/admin/index.php?id=salesman/addsalesman">Add Salesman</a></li>
    <li><a href="/admin/index.php?id=salesman/viewsalesman">View Salesman</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a>Customer Info</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="/admin/index.php?id=salesman/addsalesman">Add Salesman</a></li>
    <li><a href="/admin/index.php?id=salesman/viewsalesman">View Salesman</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</div>
```

here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZGvVW/

Comment: You mean this: <a>Contacts</a>? It doesn't have a 'href' to jump to, so it is not a properly formed link.

Comment: do you mean links without href don't work?

Comment: sorry - i meant the <li><a href="/admin/index.php">Dashboard</a></li> doesnt link anywhere even though there is a href on it

Comment: e.preventDefault(); is causing no link follow-through.

Comment: @CharlieFord - because you have e.preventDefault() in code.

Comment: Your fiddle includes jQuery code which you haven't posted, which includes e.preventDefault().

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qfPqR/

Comment: `<li>` must be in `<ul>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

e.preventDefault is cancelling navigation.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZGvVW/2/

One possible solution is to check for an href attribute.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#nav > li > a').click(function(e){
     if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
         if ($(this).attr("href") == null) {
           $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
           $(this).next().slideToggle();
           $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
           $(this).addClass('active');
           e.preventDefault();
         }
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: good, but you could cache `var $this = $(this);` to improve performance

Comment: @Shaddow: This is a cut and copy of the script he wrote in his jsfiddle, but didn't post in his question.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand a tags must have an a destination associated with them i.e. href
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTML%2FElement%2Fa#attr-href